# For loop doesn't work for image selector

Tags: javascript, html, image, for-loop, select

I'm trying to make a picture selector but the loop doesn't work.

It should make the selected div **orange**, and turn the other divs **white**.

```
function ClickPic(id)
{
    document.getElementById("pic"+id).style.backgroundColor='orange';
    for(var i = 0; i < 310; i++)
    {
        if(!i == id)
        {
            document.getElementById("pic"+i).style.backgroundColor='white';
        }
    }
}
```

The divs are turning orange when clicked, but others stay orange too.

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 1):

Looking into your function and your need, looks like you want something like this..

You can run my working example:

```js
function ClickPic(id)
{
    // Get the div and set the div orange    
    var selected_div = document.getElementById("pic"+id);
    selected_div.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
  
    // Looping through 16 divs i've created
    for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if(i != id) // Changed the operation
        {
            document.getElementById("pic"+i).style.backgroundColor='white';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.my-div{
   background-color: white;
   height: 30px; 
   width: 30px;
   cursor: pointer;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   float:left;
   margin: 0 10px 10px 0
}
```

```html
<div id="pic0" onclick="ClickPic('0')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic1" onclick="ClickPic('1')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic2" onclick="ClickPic('2')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic3" onclick="ClickPic('3')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic4" onclick="ClickPic('4')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic5" onclick="ClickPic('5')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic6" onclick="ClickPic('6')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic7" onclick="ClickPic('7')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic8" onclick="ClickPic('8')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic9" onclick="ClickPic('9')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic10" onclick="ClickPic('10')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic11" onclick="ClickPic('11')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic12" onclick="ClickPic('12')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic13" onclick="ClickPic('13')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic14" onclick="ClickPic('14')" class="my-div"></div>
<div id="pic15" onclick="ClickPic('15')" class="my-div"></div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(i != id)
{
    document.getElementById("pic"+i).style.backgroundColor='white';
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work. the divs are turning orange when clicked, but others stay orange too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.
because there are some div id missing (example pic0,pic3,pic66)
i have to check if the div exists first.

```
function ClickSkin(id)
{
    // Get the div and set the div orange    
    var selected_div = document.getElementById("pic"+id);
    selected_div.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';

    for(var i = 0; i < 310; i++)
    {
        if(document.getElementById("pic"+i))
        {
            if(i != id)
            {
                document.getElementById("pic"+i).style.backgroundColor='white';
            }
        }
    }
}
```